# Making Umlauts in ubuntu 17.10 on a ThinkPad430

Tags: keyboard

how do you do Umlauts in ubuntu 17.10? I need vowels with nipples!

I have a Think Pad T430

I can't find a 'compose' key under keyboards. I don't really know what 4th level means or where it is found, Google has let me down- I am bewildered.

Comment: What keyboard are you using (which language)? Would you be prepared to install another language and switch, when you need umlauts?

Comment: If I used a German keyboard, why would I ever need to switch back to USA keyboard?

Comment: You can find compose key setting in either gnome-tweak-tool (easy to set) or dconf-editor (a little harder to set).

Answer (score 2):

### Suggested method

If you use the US English keyboard with international symbols via <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, you can type umlauts without switching keyboard.

This works at least in the X session (maybe not in Wayland). The following command line works for me (in Ubuntu 17.10),

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us -variant altgr-intl
```

When you use this keyboard setting 'as usual' you will have the usual mapping of the keys as illustrated by the **first screenshot** with an Onboard keyboard.

[image]

As you can see in the **second screenshot** with an Onboard keyboard, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> lets you type several special characters including the umlauts, that you want.

[image]

### Alternative: Onboard and German keyboard

Using an Onboard keyboard it is also possible to switch temporarily to a German keyboard and see the layout (even if you use a US English physical keyboard). This might be more convenient if you want to type a lot in German, but if you type only a few random umlauts, the US English keyboard with international symbols via <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is probably the best choice.

### Link

See the following link for more details,

[wiki.debian.org/Keyboard](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard)

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Wow actually.  Leo   QUESTION ANSWERED!

Comment: @LeoRivers If you find this answer useful you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it.