# One keyboard two languages on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard-layout, 17.10, language-support, input-language

How can I have one keyboard input layout and multiples languages in Ubuntu 17.10? If I have English language I can't type "'e" and get an "é", as I can do in Portuguese and Spanish.

When I manage to do that on Settings -> Region & Language, I'm able to change languages, but it also changes the keyboard layout.

Is there any way to change language (Portuguese or Spanish for example) and set the keyboard input layout (US International for example)?

Comment: You can set the keyboard input layout to US International according to this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/967708/making-umlauts-in-ubuntu-17-10-on-a-thinkpad430/968758#968758; `setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us -variant altgr-intl` while a simple command would be for example `setxkbmap es` for Spanish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The US International keyboard layout isn't designed for [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) because the target language is English and English doesn't use diacritics (it should, at least for foreign words like *fiancé* or *coupé*, but it doesn't and it sometimes results in an incorrect pronunciation like "coupe" instead of "coupeh" - I'm looking at you US citizens, in the other side of the pound we do pronounce it correctly).

In order to use input languages requiring diacritics users must choose the "**US International with dead keys**" variant, with caveats:

- The apostrophe key is the same for the acute diacritic symbol. With "dead keys" you must press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> after the key.
- As above, quotation marks is used for diaeresis (umlaut) therefore if you want the quotation mark instead, you need to press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> after the key.
- As a general rule all the characters with diacritics are produced by a sequence of two keys, first the diacritic symbol then the letter - Example: **à** is obtained by pressing <kbd>`</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> - the same way used with French, Spanish (and others) keyboard layouts.
- Other special characters aren't so obvious as the example above. For instance, for the character **ç**, used in Portuguese and Catalan, there are two ways: 1. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or 2. <kbd>'</kbd> folowed by <kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: It really look like what I need, but there is no option of that here...
I can see a lot of English options, but no dead keys. What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: @mqueirozcorreia: Select _English (United States)_ and then you'll find _English (US, international with dead keys)_ in the next window.

Comment: “The apostrophe key is the same for the acute diacritic symbol. With "dead keys" you must press `SPACE` after the key.”—Or the dead key twice.  Although personally I would prefer `Space`.

Comment: Nice! I think it is very important to add "Select English (United States) and then you'll find English (US, international with dead keys) in the next window", if possible with image to help anyone who found this answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a newly created account it might happen that the current input source is changed undesirably if you change the (display) language. However, once you have switched input source explicitly once or twice, the selected (display) language and the current input source should be mutually independent.

Consequently, the answer to your question is yes. You can have any combination of (display) language and input source.

Comment: How can I set my layout (US International) using diacritics? Type "'e" and get an "é".

Comment: @mqueirozcorreia: See my comment under MichaelBay's answer.