# How to type Italian characters from US keyboard with Italian characters

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I successfully added Italian as a second input language for my keyboard.  By using the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> key I can switch from English to Italian.  The icon in the menu bar indicates this.  When I select the keyboard layout chart for the Italian, some keys have 4 letters on them.

I cannot figure out how to access any of these different options.

For example, looking at the keyboard layout, the **o** key has 4 letters: small **o** and uppercase **O**, and the same with a grave accent.  How do I get the accented ones to be used?

Comment: You access them via <AltGr> or <Right Alt> (with or without <Shift>).

Comment: Maybe you are helped by an [Onboard keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967708/making-umlauts-in-ubuntu-17-10-on-a-thinkpad430/968758#968758) in order to display what is possible to type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "level 3 select key" to access those characters. Usually the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (aka right <kbd>Alt</kbd>) key is the level 3 select key. For the fourth character use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need accentuated letters you could also use the US international keyboard with deadkeys. There to get an ò you simply type first the backquote (accent grave), then 'o'. To get a backquote alone you type backquote followed by space.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The first answer using the right alternate key worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much difference in the characters. I keep English (US) layout, enable the "compose key" as right alt, and then to get ò for example its three key presses:

> right alt, o,`