# Kubuntu 17.10 on screen keyboard

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, plasma, accessibility

I can't seem to find the on screen keyboard in Kubuntu 17.10 with Plasma 5.10.

Is there anything I need to install\do to activate it?

I could not find any settings related to on screen\touch keyboard, and was unable to find an answer so far.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
The only place I could see it is on the Lockscreen, the one that appears if device stays idle for a few minutes.

However there's no keyboard on the initial login screen, and neither can I find any buttons to bring it up when working.

Which is a shame, as otherwise with large fonts and double-tap scroll KDE seems to be quite capable of being used on tablet with no keyboard.

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install onboard`

Comment: See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967708/making-umlauts-in-ubuntu-17-10-on-a-thinkpad430/968758#968758). I would guess, that after installing `onboard`, you can find it and start it via the menu, and if necessary, put it in the 'startup application' directory. If you log in automatically, you need not worry about the login screen.

Comment: Onboard is great, thanks, but I can't seem to get any keyboard on Login Screen. IT does work on LockScreen though. I tried editing sddm.conf file with InputMethod=qtvirtualkeyboard and even export QT_IM_MODULE=qtvirtualkeyboard as root, did not help so far. Auto-login may work as a temporary workaround, but it's not safe, i want to password protect my tablet, which, by nature, is easy to get into wrong hands.

Comment: What about the solution in this link: [On-Screen Keyboard on Login? - Kubuntu Forums](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwztCar6zaAhUREVAKHekJCsYQFghTMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kubuntuforums.net%2Fshowthread.php%2F65841-On-Screen-Keyboard-on-Login&usg=AOvVaw3gx96pJMb76IZB1sgZlqg1)

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to onboard:

```
sudo apt-get install florence
```